# Python : To list files if my keyword contains using regular expression

Tags: java, python, regex, classpath

Python: (.py file)

I have to pass a property file's path which resides inside a jar in to the classpath while java complile.

```
vmargs = {
"-DApplicationName" : "myApp",
"-Dport" : "8080",
"-DpropertyFile" : "WEB-INF/library/JARFILE-45.33.jar:/properties/somefile.property"
}
```

The above code works fine when JARFILE has the version 45.33. But how can i give the path dynamically something like:

> "-DpropertyFile" :
>   "WEB-INF/library/JARFILE-(RegEx).jar:/properties/somefile.property"

NB:
The version (45.33) can be any number of charector. Example as follows:

```
Beta-44.55
Beta1-33.33
7777.ee44
44.22222
```

Comment: So what is the problem? .jar files are just zip files, you can read them with zlib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with the following

```
>>> import re
>>> test = "WEB-INF/library/JARFILE-45.33.jar:/properties/somefile.property"
>>> sub = r"WEB-INF/library/JARFILE-[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.jar:/properties/somefile\.property"
>>> print(re.match(sub, test))
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fd9ab1de718>
```

Here's the important part:

First we need to ensure that any wildcards (such as ".") are properly escaped, using a backslash.

```
# old
"WEB-INF/library/JARFILE-45.33.jar:/properties/somefile.property"
# new
"WEB-INF/library/JARFILE-45\.33\.jar:/properties/somefile\.property"
```

Next you mentioned it can be any character, string or number, so you can use the following set:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]
```

This will match any number or any letter a-z (upper or lowercase), but only one. By adding a '+' after, it will match 1 or more elements.

We should be able to match our string with our regex.